# Can we define the group SU(2) without using matrices?

Tags: group-theory, definition

If instead in terms of matrices, the group U(2) is defined as the set of all unitary operators in two-dimensional complex vector space that leaves the norm (or norm square) of vectors, $$||\vec{v}||^2=(\vec{v},\vec{v}),$$ unchanged, how will the [group SU(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group) be defined in this language, without matrices?

Comment: Fix a finite-dimensional complex inner product space $(V,g)$. Then, we define $U(g)$ to be the set of all unitary linear operators $V\to V$, and define $SU(g)$ to be the set of all unitary linear operators having determinant $+1$. If you choose $V=\Bbb{C}^n$ and $g$ to be the usual hermitian inner product $g(z,w)=\sum_{a=1}^nz_a\overline{w}_a$ (or the other way with your conjugates) you get the usual definition of $U(n)$ and $SU(n)$.

Comment: What is meant by the determinant of an operator? I know the determinant of square matrices.

Comment: There are several ways of defining it. The most common is to fix a basis and define it to be the determinant of the matrix representation; then check that the definition is basis-independent (which it is because changing bases causes the matrices to be related by a similarity transformation). Alternatively, if you know about exterior algebra, then you know the top exterior power is 1-dimensional, so the induced linear operator on the top exterior power is a multiple of the identity; this multiple is the determinant. You can google both these approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You can deine $SU(2)$ by the quaternions $\mathbb{H}$, by taking the numbers $z= a+bi+cj+dk$ such that $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=1$. This set with standard quaternion multiplication turns out to be a group, namely $SU(2)$. This is actually a construction that can be much more generalised, and we get the $Spin(p,q)$ groups and Clifford Algebras $Cl(p,q)$. In this case, we constructed $\mathbb{H}=Cl(0,3)$ and $SU(2)=Spin(0,3)$, where the $3$ indicates, that we have three independent complex units:$i^2=j^2=k^2=-1$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by $+DGL$, but I think the point you're making is this: with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Matrix_representations) matrix representation $q$ has determinant $|q|^4$, so we get a representation of just the special unitary group.

Comment: Ups, the +DGL was autocorrection, I edited it now

Comment: @J.G. That’s one way to formulate it, absolutely!

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.